# notwithstanding keyword

Tags: go

What does the `notwithstanding` keyword mean in Google Go?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

**2017 Update**: There was a major parser update and the new one no longer seems to support these Easter egg words.

---

Looks like an easter egg in the lexer to me:

https://github.com/golang/go/blob/08e25fc1ba397e02ec776561ed73b7f9a8b94392/src/cmd/compile/internal/gc/lex.go#L2152-L2156

the relevant section is the symbol table:

```
"notwithstanding",      LIGNORE,    Txxx,       OXXX,
"thetruthofthematter",  LIGNORE,    Txxx,       OXXX,
"despiteallobjections", LIGNORE,    Txxx,       OXXX,
"whereas",              LIGNORE,    Txxx,       OXXX,
"insofaras",            LIGNORE,    Txxx,       OXXX,
```

I guess they could be used to test handling of the lexical type LIGNORE, but there doesn't seem to be any "real" ignored tokens.

Comment: ugh, their lexer function has a label called 'l0' (el-zero) for the beginning statement. compilers should just be designed to delete your code if you actually use l0 as an identifier in your code.

Comment: What if you are working within a domain where l0 has a specific meaning? After all lower case pi is just a single letter in greek but we still accept it as the name for an identifier, since we know what it means.

Comment: @Jørgen Fogh: I wasn't being serious, but it did cause another answer to this question (which has since been deleted) to say: "Theses all point to "GOTO 10" which I can't find at the moment" which perfectly illustrates the problem. Of course there can be exceptions to every rule.

Comment: This is still the case for [Go 1.5](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/08e25fc1ba397e02ec776561ed73b7f9a8b94392/src/cmd/compile/internal/gc/lex.go#L2152-L2156)

Answer (score 8):

The [Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec) does not include the keyword 'notwithstanding'.