# What are the 5 secret keywords in Go?

Tags: go

In [this talk](https://youtu.be/ynoY2xz-F8s?t=9m), Francesc Campoy has a slide with Go's 25 keywords, and apparently 5 'secret' keywords.

What are the 5 secret keywords in Go?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The following 5 keywords are ignored:

```
notwithstanding
thetruthofthematter
despiteallobjections
whereas
insofaras
```

[Yes, really](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/b4e9f70412671c7ac06b4852c38a0ab82d94ddf5/src/cmd/compile/internal/gc/lex.go#L605-L609).

---

Update: As Deleplace notes in the comments, the easter egg keywords have been removed. It looks like [this commit](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/57df2f802f0417f08100ff8002f3b062e695e148#diff-76741800172ea45f1e1b32be16e1097b) took them out during a major parser update. If you try to run [a program containing one of these tokens](https://play.golang.org/p/EAVnxSY9o41), you'll find they're treated as ordinary identifiers now.

Comment: Not anymore!
They were nice and useful and concise, while they lasted

Answer (score 8):

There are some easter egg keywords in the lexer ([lex.go](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/08e25fc1ba397e02ec776561ed73b7f9a8b94392/src/cmd/compile/internal/gc/lex.go#L2152-L2156)) that are not in the official documentation, and hence are ignored by the compiler.

Here they are:

```
notwithstanding
thetruthofthematter
despiteallobjections
whereas
insofaras
```

You can report to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489803/google-go-notwithstanding-keyword) conversation for more details.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the secret keywords will be removed in v1.10. See [here](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/57df2f802f0417f08100ff8002f3b062e695e148#r19581522).

For anyone curious, [here](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/8c195bdf120ea86ddda42df89df7bfba80afdf10/src/cmd/internal/gc/lex.go#L2445-L2469) is the commit which introduced the keywords.

Comment: They actually date to well before that. You'll see them in the original C compiler sources committed to the repo: https://github.com/golang/go/blob/0cafb9ea3d3d34627e8f492ccafa6ba9b633a213/src/cmd/gc/lex.c#L863-L867 . Rob only knows where they came from before that...

Comment: FWIW, this commit is actually included in the history of 1.8-beta1, well before 1.10.